# In c++, how do you find all consecutive composite numbers for in an integer using for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, integer

The basic idea I want to find inside a given problem is this. I have an integer variable called N where the user can input a value to.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
```

Then from this point onward, I created a for loop that replicates how you would normally find out if the integer created is indeed prime or not. However, what I'm trying to find isn't whether the number is prime but to find all the [composites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) from a range of 2, to the number that was inputted. So if the input is 10. I should be getting composites 4 6 8 9 10 from that given range. 
I do know that the first thing to do is to create a for loop like this

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
```

Then nest another for loop with a conditional to test if each number inside the given range is a prime or composite.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                std::cout << i << " ";
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this approach isn't really cutting it. What's really going on inside this nested for loop approach is an out put beginning with 2 3 2 4 5 2 and a bunch of numbers that aren't making much sense. What is it about this approach that's causing this wacky sequence of numbers outputted and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've printed a composite number, you want the inner "for j" loop to terminate and the outer "for i" loop to advance, so after `std::cout` add `break;`.  Additionally, you know if you let `j == i` you'll deem any number a composite, so change the "for j" loop termination condition from `j <= i` to `j < i`.  [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3b3b463f294f904) to working code....

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. I completely forgot about the break statement. One last thing I need some clarification with. Although I have all the composites. One thing I'm looking towards is to just output the consecutive composites. So instead of 4 6 8 9 10. I get 8 9 10. I know I can add an array into this whole algorithm to make things easier but lets say I just want to output the consecutive ascending 8 9 10 of the composites? How would would go about doing that?

Comment: That's a little ambiguous - if `n` was 16 say, you'd want 8 9 10 14 15 16?  (For the simpler case where you'd output nothing unless all results were contiguous, you can push_back the results into a vector<int> then check for contiguousness before printing).  See a working solution [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f7d6aba503fefdf).  The trick is comparing new composites with the last one printed, but further complicated by making sure you print the last composite in each contiguous group....

Comment: More generally, learning to program is about nutting this stuff out... you should have a good go yourself before asking for solutions ;-p.  I recommend learning to use an interactive debugger too - you can see where your program starts to do unwanted/unexpected things and reason about how to correct it.